# Blank GridView on scrolling

Tags: android

I encountered this very weird behavior:

I have a `GridView` with each item having a `RatingBar` and `ImageView`. It displays just fine. Even when I scroll down down, it shows as expected. However, if I scroll down-up-down(..) in fast succession, everything goes white and I see nothing(the `GridView` disappears).

*Any* clues?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I got the same in my app. If yes please post the answer or hint.

Comment: I was able to solve it by reducing the size of images shown in grid. I think I applied an factor of 33% - to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `cacheColorHint = #00000000` in XML or in Code.